# How to search a particular string in table without mentioning the column name in which that string belong in mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I want to search a `string 'Trevor DSouza'` in table without mentioning the column name which this string belongs. This string might me stored in different different column.so for search this string I wrote my query like:-

```
SELECT * FROM claim_master 
WHERE MATCH (type,cheque) AGAINST('Trevor DSouza' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

when I am executing this query it shows error like:-

> Error Code: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

so to resolve this error I have created one FULLTEXT index on cheque as:-

```
ALTER TABLE claim_master ADD fulltext my_index(cheque);
```

so then after I am trying to execute my query:-

```
SELECT * FROM claim_master
WHERE MATCH(type,cheque) AGAINST('Trevor DSouza' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

it again show me the same error as:-

> Error Code: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

also at the one time how I can check a search string in all column. is there any way of passing the column name in match function like:- `MATCH(full_name,mode,cheque,particular,desrption,final_status)`??  and if there is a way of passing the columns at one time,then first we have to create a FULLTEXT index for that columns????? how to do this????

please help me to solve this.i am badly get stuck at this query

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an fulltext index on the same columns as the `MATCH(...)` you are going to use.

`ALTER TABLE claim_master ADD fulltext my_index(type,cheque);`